# Throws and catch clauses

Tags: java, exception

I am having trouble understanding exception handling, unfortunately it just really confuses me. So, I have to implement exception codes that have been created by my teacher in another code with try and catch blocks. I understand the majority of the try and catch blocks, but I don't know how to use the exceptions that have been created and print out the information in their constructors. This is one of the exceptions that she created

```
    * This exception should be used when the hours worked value for an hourly employee
     * is found to be less than 1 or greater than 84.
     *
     * When using this exception, if at all possible, pass a String containing employee SSN
     *  to the constructor.  The SSN will then be displayed as part of the exception      message,
     *  thus allowing the invalid record to be more easily located.
     */

     public class InvalidHoursWorkedException extends Exception
     {
     /**
     * No-arg constructor
     */

     public InvalidHoursWorkedException()
     {
      super("\nInvalid Hours Worked");
     }

     /**
     * The following constructor accepts the employee's SSN
     * as an argument.  The SSN will be displayed in the error message
     * for the exception.
    */

   public InvalidHoursWorkedException(String ssn)
   {
      super("\nHours Worked are <1.0 or >84.0 Employee cannot be processed: " + ssn );
   }
}
```

And this is what I have so far. I don't know if it's right nor do I know how to pass the ssn variable in the set method for InvalidHoursWorkedException.

```
 public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee

  /*
   * You will need to add a throws clause to the class header.
   * List each of the exceptions that may be thrown by the constructor
   */
{
   private double hrsWorked;
   private double hrlyRate;

//   private double weeklyPay;  // hourly pay per week

   // five-argument constructor -- additional arguments are hours worked & hourly rate
   public HourlyEmployee( String first, String last, String ssn,
      double hours, double rate ) throws InvalidHoursWorkedException
   {
      super( first, last, ssn ); // pass to Employee constructor
    /*
     * Before executing each "set" method for hours worked, test the argument.
     * If hours worked does not fall into the proper range, throw the associated exception,
     *  else, execute the set method.
     */

       try
       {
      setHrsWorked( hours ); 
       }
       catch(InvalidHoursWorkedException invalidHoursWorkedException)
       {
          System.err.printf(invalidHoursWorkedException.getMessage());
       }
     // validate & store hours worked this week

       setHrlyRate( rate );  // validate & store hourly rate

   }// end of five item constructor

   //set hours worked
   public void setHrsWorked( double hours )  throws InvalidHoursWorkedException 
   {
   if(hours < 0 && hours > 84)
       throw new InvalidHoursWorkedException();
   else
   {
   hrsWorked = hours;

   }
   }
```

this is the changed code after some of the comments. I still don't know if I need to throw the exception in the constructor header and the set method header

```
  public HourlyEmployee( String first, String last, String ssn,
      double hours, double rate ) throws InvalidHoursWorkedException
   {
      super( first, last, ssn ); // pass to Employee constructor
    /*
     * Before executing each "set" method for hours worked, test the argument.
     * If hours worked does not fall into the proper range, throw the associated exception,
     *  else, execute the set method.
     */

       try
       {
      setHrsWorked( hours ); 
       }
       catch(InvalidHoursWorkedException invalidHoursWorkedException)
       {
         throw new InvalidHoursWorkedException(ssn); 

       }
     // validate & store hours worked this week

       setHrlyRate( rate );  // validate & store hourly rate

   }
```

I feel like my set method is still off

```
  public void setHrsWorked( double hours )  throws InvalidHoursWorkedException 
   {
   if(hours < 0 && hours > 84)
       throw new InvalidHoursWorkedException();
   else
   {
   hrsWorked = hours;

   }
   }
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this is C#?

Comment: Someone else thinks it's Java.

Comment: @user, you may want to tag your question with a language.

Comment: It's Java. See the call to super() instead of base() and "extends" as opposed to ":"

Comment: Sorry, this is for java. I am new to this site, so I didn't really know the correct way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is what you wanted implement the other logic yourself

```
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee

{
    private double hrsWorked;
    private double hrlyRate;

    public HourlyEmployee(String first, String last, String ssn,
                          double hours, double rate) throws InvalidHoursWorkedException {
        super(first, last, ssn); // pass to Employee constructor

        try {
            setHrsWorked(hours);
        } catch (InvalidHoursWorkedException invalidHoursWorkedException) {
            System.out.println(invalidHoursWorkedException.getMessage());
        }
        // validate & store hourly rate

    }// end of five item constructor

    //set hours worked
    public void setHrsWorked(double hours) throws InvalidHoursWorkedException {
        if (hours > 0 || hours < 84)
            throw new InvalidHoursWorkedException();
        else {
            hrsWorked = hours;
            System.out.println("Hours set to "+hrsWorked);

        }
    }
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        try {
            HourlyEmployee h = new HourlyEmployee("abc","def","xyz",100,10);
        } catch (InvalidHoursWorkedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using the try and catch clauses in a main method though. If I throw the exception in the constructor because it is calling the set method for hours worked, then do I need to throw the same exception in the set method?

Comment: have the employee and InvalidHoursWorkedException class implementation i hope yu can do that let me know if some issue is there

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused by your last comment.

Comment: Well, the post test has the print messages, I just need to pass the ssn through the exception constructor. I don't know if I need to do that in the set method or the constructor, because when I try to pass the ssn in the set method through the exception constructor it says variable is unrecognizable.

Comment: Oh, I see you out the message too in the main method. How do I pass the ssn variable then? Thank you for the help too!!

Comment: If you see the constructor of HourlyEmployee the ssn is already passed to it and using super in HourlyEmployee constuctor Employee object is initialized with ssn fname and lname with employee object perform whichever implementation you want for ssn

Answer (score 0):

You mention throws in your method when you want the caller of the method to know what exception it might throw. But it your case you are catching the exception in the catch clause, so you don't have to mention throws in your method. Since it will never be thrown

Comment: Well, I have to throw an exception if the hours aren't right, so I don't throw the exception in the set method or the constructor?

Comment: So for that what you can do is 
           try
           {
              setHrsWorked( hours ); 
           }
           catch(InvalidHoursWorkedException invalidHoursWorkedException)
           {
throw new InvalidHoursWorkedException(ssn)
              
           }

Comment: So, I don't need to throw in the System.err.print statement then, if I do that? And do I keep the throws clause in both the constructor and the set method?

Answer (score 0):

One of your constructors of HourlyEmployee states it is capable of throwing InvalidHoursException, which it does if the hours are less than 0, or greater that 84.

Whenever you call setHours, if the hours does not pass your validation, that exception is thrown. Note setHours is also called from within one of your constructors.

InvalidHoursException inherits from Exception, so to catch it, you could just catch all exceptions. If you need it to do something special, you could catch InvalidHoursException in one block and generic exceptions in another.

As for the message, you can see the call to super(message) overload. To get that message, just call .getMessage() on your InvalidHoursException instance.

Something like this...

```
try{
    HourlyEmployee hrEmp = new HourlyEmployee("John", "Smith", "123-45-6789", 85, 500.00)
}
(catch InvalidHoursException ihe){
    String message = ihe.getMessage();
    // do something with message here...
}
```

Comment: Well, there is post test program that is written to test all these exceptions. the message is already written in the constructor, so do I need to use the getMessage() in order to print it out or can I just use the changed code that I used, where I just pass the ssn through the exception constructor? Exception handling and I just don't see eye to eye for some reason. Thanks for the help!

Comment: And I need to pass the ssn variable to be added into that message and for some reason it won't work in the set method when I try to pass it with the exception.

Comment: Oh and she has the getMessage() methods in her post test program.

Comment: Remember you can add any properties to an exception class you've created. An exception is like any other class. You can set SSN, Name, heck, you can even set it up to access a database, if you're into that sort of thing. What makes exceptions different is you can throw and catch them. So, when you catch them, you can access the methods and/or properties as you see fit